# Is there a substitute for "sf" package?

Tags: r, coordinates, geospatial, shapefile, r-sf

I´m trying to find a package similar to "sf" so I can:

1. Define the coordinates from a shape database as when I use "st_as_sf".
2. Define the specific coordinates characteristics as when I use "st_transform".

I need a replacement for "sf" because I haven´t been able to install it on my computer.

Many thanks in advance!

```
Scoor <- st_as_sf(DataBase, coords = c("Longitude",                                              
"Latitude"), crs = 4326) 
Scoor <- st_transform(Scoor, "+proj=utm +zone=15N +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83")
```

Comment: You'd probably do better to ask how you can install sf on your computer

Comment: You can use `rgdal`, `sp` packages.

Comment: Thank you both!
Hong Ooi: I haven´t been able to install "sf" (I´m using Linux) because it says that I´m missing udunits2, then I got an error message that says: "-----Error: libudunits2.a not found-----". I´ve tried so many possibilities but any of them worked. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bappa Das: thanks!

Comment: Do you get errors trying to [install `udunits2`](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf#ubuntu) ?

Comment: Have you followed the instructions here: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf ?

Comment: @EdzerPebesma: Hi! Yes. I had followed them but I still was getting an error "libudunits2.a not found"

Answer (score 1):

Thank you both @SymbolixAU and @Edzer. I solved this problem by using:

```
module load R/3.6.0
module load udunits # for sf
module load geos # for sf
module load gdal/2.0.1 # for rgdal
module load proj # for rgdal
install.packages('rgdal', type = "source", configure.args=c('--with-proj-include=/panfs/roc/msisoft/proj/4.9.3/include','--with-proj-lib=/panfs/roc/msisoft/proj/4.9.3/lib'))
install.packages('sf')
```

Comment: What does `module load R/3.6.0` mean? Its not R code. Is this some operating system installation command?